# RxJava combine database create/update call for a list of objects

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room, rx-android

im currently struggeling with my first more complex rx chain, maybe you can help me out. 
I have a list of objects, which i get from an api call. I need to check if they exists local, if they do, update the dataset, if not create them. My current approach is something like this:

```
 private fun insertUpdateFromServer(objectsToInsert: List<Model>): Completable {
    return Observable.fromIterable(objectsToInsert).flatMapCompletable { atl ->
        dao.getByServerId(atl.id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .switchIfEmpty { obs: SingleObserver<in Model> -> createNewObject(atl) }.flatMapCompletable {
                    updateObject(atl, it).applySchedulers()
                }
    }
```

Its important, that i have to wait for all the subtasks to complete. This is working if i only have objcts to update, but if there is a new object, the whole thing will not complete.

Note that im only interested if the operation is completed, the emitted object doesnt matter for me. The function "getByServerId" returns a Maybe.

So im asking you if you can point out my logical mistakes and push me in the right direction, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

`switchIfEmpty { obs: SingleObserver<in Model> -> createNewObject(atl) }`

Kotlin's automatic SAM conversion is trying to make your life easier by generating an overload of `switchIfEmpty` that implements `void subscribe` from `SingleSource`. In not all cases is this helpful however, what you want to be using instead is this:

`switchIfEmpty(createNewObject(atl))`

A better explanation of why this is happening can be found [here.](https://medium.com/@dmstocking/rxjava2-kotlin-gotcha-concatwith-mergewith-15bcc460f7e3)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! But this does not solve my problem completely, because now the function adding the object AND updating it after this. Is there a possibility to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

So i ended up with a workaround which i found [here](https://medium.com/my-random-thoughts-in-software-engineering/null-handling-with-rxjava-2-maybe-t-and-some-little-tricky-details-c26b47bd4fc2).

TL;DR: Maybe emits null and calls then "onComplete". So i can chain this if i use "onSuccess" and "onComplete".

The code for someone who is interested:

```
     private fun insertUpdateFromServer(objects: List<Model>): Completable {
    return Observable.fromIterable(objects)
            .flatMapCompletable { obj ->
                dao.getByServerId(obj.id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .doOnComplete { createNewObject(obj).subscribe() }
                        .doOnSuccess { updateObject(obj, it).applySchedulers().subscribe() }
                        .flatMapCompletable { Completable.complete() }
            }
}
```

This expression waits for all it subtasks to terminate and terminates then completely.